# How can I get the max decimal value of n-digit number in Java?

Tags: java, math

In our code, we have the maximum number of digits allowed (say, `8`) in a decimal (as in base 10) number. **How can I use this number to see if a possible value is within that range (`0` to `99,999,999`)?**

If we were working with binary numbers, I'd do something like:

```
value < 1<<(MAX + 1)
```

but of course that won't work for decimal. I also considered something like:

```
Long.toString(value).length() < MAX
```

but that seems much too heavy.

Comment: It is possible to value to be negative?

Answer (score 8):

```
if (value >= 0 && value < Math.pow(10, MAX))
```

Comment: what if the value is negative?

Comment: The question does say "range 0 to …"

Comment: that has to be checked right? did it say input will be non-negative?

Comment: @Anil great point! Currently, we're using a custom on-screen input that only allows positive numbers, but that might not always be the case.

Answer (score 3):

Use [log](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10(double)) base 10 to get the number of digits in a base 10 number

```
if ((int)(Math.log10(value) + 1) <= MAX) {
    ...
}
```

If you don't have access to log10, you can use normal log to do this:

```
int length = (int)(Math.log(value) / Math.log(10)) + 1;
if (length <= MAX) {
    ...
}
```

Note this also works for any base, so using the second method above, you can replace the 10 with any base and you have the length of that number in the given base

Comment: Why the `+ 1`? I think this might make a false negative with `MAX = 8` and `value = 99999999` because `Math.log10(99999999) == 8` and `(int)(8 + 1) <= 8)` is `false`.

Comment: It actually returns a double value - 7.99999... The cast to int rounds down so it is in fact still 8 even after the +1. The reason you add one is really just to avoid having to say that the length of a single digit number is zero

Answer (score 1):

You can take 10 to the (nth) power;

```
  value < (Math.pow (10, num_digits))
```

… for positive integer fixnums; if you're more concerned with magnitude than sign, perhaps use the absolute value:

```
  Math.abs(value) < (Math.pow (10, num_digits))
```

This, of course, doesn't apply to floating-point or BigDecimal values, but the same (analogous, using method calls) works for arbitrarily large bignums using BigInteger.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?
`val>=0 && (value/1000000000)==0` ?

Comment: No, because `MAX` can change.